# Child control Tag in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OpenDocument">
            <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink Name="hypFileLocation" Foreground="{StaticResource XceedHyperLinkForeground}"  Cursor="Hand"  Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}, Path=DataContext[OpenLocation]}" Click="Hyperlink_Click">
          <TextBlock Name="tblkDocumentName" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}, Path=DataContext[DocumentName]}"   Text="View" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}, Path=DataContext[DocumentName]}"/>
        </Hyperlink>
      </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

In xaml, I set tag for both hyperlink & Textblock inside hyperlink. I want to retreive the textblock tag value in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189715/how-to-access-a-control-inside-the-data-template-in-c-sharp-metro-ui-in-the-code

Comment: And what have *you* tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this....Within the click or tap event handler:

I'm not sure about the `TextBlock` value but you could easily get the `HyperLink` value.

in .cs, within the event handler: This is a sample

```
 HyperLink asd = (HyperLink)sender;

 WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();            
 webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri(asd.Tag.ToString());//here you could get the value
 webBrowserTask.Show();
```

Like wise try it for the `Textblock` and see.

For more you could refer these:

[Getting selected value of listbox windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894108/)

Hope it helps!